# Java - limit ArrayList to only 250 digits

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a project which uses an ArrayList to store timestamps. With this ArrayList, I calculate the average parking time for each car within a garage. If I run my project for let's say 5 minutes, that specific ArrayList has already been loaded with about 10.000 different timestamps. Therefore I want to limit the whole ArrayList to only 250 to prevent it from overloading. If the ArrayList is a certain size, it takes forever to loop through it. It needs to push the new times to the ArrayList but delete the older ones so it is still able to calculate the average time. How can I achieve this?

**The ArrayList**

```java
private ArrayList<Float> times = new ArrayList<Float>();
```

**Adding the  times to the ArrayList**

```java
private void carsPaying() {
        // Let cars pay.
        float total = 0.0f;
        int i = 0;
        while (paymentCarQueue.carsInQueue()>0 && i < Car.getPaymentSpeed()){
            Car car = paymentCarQueue.removeCar();

            if(currentDay != Time.getDay()) {
                weeklyRevenue[Time.getDay()] = 0;
                currentDay = Time.getDay();
            }
            // TODO Handle payment.
            float payment = car.getTotalMinutes() * 0.042f;

            weeklyRevenue[Time.getDay()] += payment;

            revenue += payment;

            carLeavesSpot(car);
            numberOfParkedCars--;
            numberOfCarsLeft++;

            float timeInFloat = car.getTotalMinutes();

            times.add(timeInFloat);

            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(total);

    }
```

**Calculate the average Time**

```java
public BigDecimal getAverageTime() {

        float totalTime = 0.0f;

        for(Float time : times) {
            totalTime += time;
        }

        float average = totalTime / times.size();
        average = average / 60;
        int hour = (int) average;
        int minuut = (int) (60 * (average - hour));

        float temp1 = (float) minuut / 100;
        float temp2 = hour + temp1;

        return round(temp2, 2);

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to delete the old data from `ArrayList` after it reached 250?

Comment: Yeah if that is possible? To only let newer ones in so it still updates if that makes any sense?

Comment: You're using `float` for monetary values. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of elements is fixed, you should use an array instead. It's easy to overwrite the oldest elements using the modulo operator, like this:

```
private static final int MAX_SIZE = 250;
private float[] times = new float[MAX_SIZE];

private void carsPaying() {
        // ...
        while (paymentCarQueue.carsInQueue() > 0 && i < Car.getPaymentSpeed()) {
            // ...
            times[i % MAX_SIZE] = timeInFloat;
            i++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a strategy like this

```java
Queue<Float> times = new ArrayDeque<>();

final static int MAX_SIZE = 250;

public void addTime(float time) { 
 if(times.size() == MAX_SIZE) times.poll();
 times.add(time); 
}

// continue your average calculation the maximum size the times queue will ever 
// get is 250
```

Comment: This will still let newer times in the Queue? So if the Queue is full and I push a new time in the Queue this one will get ignored? or also pushed in the Queue and another one will be deleted?

Comment: it will discard the first inserted time i.e the oldest one and insert your new time to the end of the queue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Guava then you can use a class called EvictingQueue see https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html.  It isn't a list but it does implment iterable which means you can easily search through it.

Comment: is it really a good idea to pull all of guava just for simple functionality that could easily be achieved by a normal `Queue` and a little bit of logic .

Comment: I prefer to not write code that someone else has probably written better; I use apache commons for string manipulation and apache IO for common IO stuff too.  You can cut out uneeded code if you want to when you do your build with multiple tools.  It depends if you think you're better than the others I think; me I'm a flawed individual :)

Comment: i'm not saying that i can write better code than the libraries already offers, the code already existing has been tested and used by thousands of developers so no questions there, i was only mentioning the fact that maybe it's overkill to pull a whole library (`guava` in this case) for something that you can achieve by simply using what's already offered by the jdk :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `add(int index, E element)` instead of `add(E element)` and reinitialize the counter to `0` to keep more recent elements :

```
int i = 0;
while (paymentCarQueue.carsInQueue()>0 && i < Car.getPaymentSpeed()){
    // ...
    float timeInFloat = car.getTotalMinutes();
    times.add(i, timeInFloat);
    i++;
    if (i == MAX_TIMES-1) { i = 0 };
}
```

Note that it will not maintain the order of the elements according to their recentness.
To maintain it, using a `Queue` as `LinkedList` is a fair possibility as adding or removing at the beginning or the end of it is cheap enough.
For example to maintain elements by ascending time :

```
LinkedList<Float> times = new LinkedList<>();
//...
while (paymentCarQueue.carsInQueue()>0 && i < Car.getPaymentSpeed()){
    // ...
    float timeInFloat = car.getTotalMinutes();
    if (times.size() == MAX_TIMES-1) { times.removeFirst()};
    times.addLast(timeInFloat);

}
```